# Create tree of processes

Tags: shell-script, process, ps, recursive, tree

I'm implementing pstree as an assignment,

and I would like to create **test tree of processes**, but I'm struggling to do so.

I tried to do something like this to create tree of background processes so I can test my script later.

recursive tree of processes

```
childProcess(){

        echo "mine PID is: "$$

        local -i level=$(expr $1 - 1)  # level of recursion

        if [[ $level -gt 0 ]]; then
          echo $level
          childProcess $level &           # we do binary tree
          echo "Process with  PID $! launched"
          childProcess $level &
          echo "Process with  PID $! launched"
          sleep $level
          echo "baf! "$level" pid is: "$$
        fi
}


# create binary tree of depth 4
for (( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )); do
    childProcess 4 &
    echo "running proces no. :"$!
done
```

But I would like to echo PID from within of process, and with this I can't.

Another not-working-solution would be this, but it creates processes in "DFS manner".

```
declare -i level=$1


if [[ $level -gt 0 ]]; then
  sh $0 $(expr $level - 1)  # spawn children
  sh $0 $(expr $level - 1)  # spawn children

  sleep 100;
  echo "level :"$level" process no: "$$
fi
```

Can anyone tell me how to construct tree of processes which I can acces by PID, and that would be there until I delete them, e.g. by killing oldest process.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a snapshot of the processes currently running on the system. The absolute minimum that you'd need is each PID and its corresponding PPID:

```bash
ps -ax -o pid=,ppid=
```

This will give you two columns of numbers that could be stored in a file and edited by hand if you want to do so. The benefit of this is that it gives you input for your program from a real running system, and it's easy to produce.

You can then work out the minimal program to read these numbers and output them in a tree-like manner, like

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' '
{
        ppid[$1] = $2
}

function print_pid(pid, level) {
        $0 = ""
        $(level+1) = pid
        print

        for (p in ppid)
                if (ppid[p] == pid)
                        print_pid(p, level + 1)
}

END {
        print_pid(1,0)
}'
```

The remaining effort would be to add the actual command names etc. to the output (you will have to ask `ps` to provide more data), and to decorate the output with simple ASCII graphics.

As far as I know, the `pstree` utility I have access to actually uses `ps` to produce its input.